# MySQL Update query depending on variable

Tags: mysql, jsp

```
<form name="atten" method="post" action="add.jsp" onSubmit="dte();">
  <p>Date:         <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="dt"></p>
  <p>No. of Hours: <input type="text" name="hours" value="" />
                   <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="sub" />
  </form>
```

A part of my Table Description is as follows:

```
   +-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   | Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
   +-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   | uid   | varchar(10) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
   | mnth  | int(2)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
   | yr    | int(4)      | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
   | a1    | int(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
   | a2    | int(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

I'm using this form to get two variables: Date and Hours.
I need to update different columns depending on the date.
Example: If the date is March 1,2014. I need to update the column a1 for a particular row(depending upon UID,etc;That I will figure out later).

Can someone help me on how to update a specific column depending upon the date.
Please feel free to ask for more information if required.

I'm using JSP and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a `CASE` inside the `UPDATE` statement, like this:

```
UPDATE table1
SET a1 = CASE 
  WHEN DATE(NOW()) = '2014-03-01' THEN '9'
  ELSE a1
  END,
a2 = CASE 
  WHEN DATE(NOW()) = '2013-01-01' THEN '6'
  ELSE a2
  END
```